# How to predict data using LinearRegression using linear_model.OLS from statsmodels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I was running a linear regression using statsmodel.api and I wanted to do the same things I can with sklearn. However, I can't seem to find a way to apply my model to the test data and get the R-squared and other things.

This is the kind of thing I get using sklearn, but can't find a way to replicate using statsmodel:

```
# import library
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# Create sample
 X_R1, y_R1 = make_regression(n_samples = 100, n_features=1,n_informative=1, bias = 150.0, noise = 30, random_state=0)

# split train / test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_R1, y_R1,random_state = 1)

# Roda o modelo
linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

# Apresenta as informacoes desejadas
print('linear model coeff (w): {}'.format(linreg.coef_))
print('linear model intercept (b): {:.3f}'.format(linreg.intercept_))
print('R-squared score (training): {:.3f}'.format(linreg.score(X_train, y_train)))
print('R-squared score (test): {:.3f}'.format(linreg.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

The output:

[image]

Now this is using statsmodel:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats

X2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
est = sm.OLS(y_train, X2)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())
```

The output in the second script is more complete, so I would like to use it. But I still need to apply the model to the test data.

Comment: What's your specific question? What's the problem you're experiencing with your code, and how is it different than what you expect?

Comment: Hey @G.Anderson, I want to get the r-squared of the test data. My understanding is that I run the model for the training data and to check how it can predict on new data, I should run for the test data.

Comment: So how was the output from your code different from what you expected? Did you get an error? Did you get a wrong result or no result? The [RegressionResults](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html) is a separate way to get more robust statistics, but again, you have asked a very broad question which really needs to be narrowed to be on-topic for stack overflow

Comment: @dekio let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy. You just need the `predict` method of the `OLS` model.

Use this:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats

X2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
est = sm.OLS(y_train, X2).fit() # this is a OLS object

X_test = sm.add_constant(X_test) # add again the constant
y_test_predicted = est.predict(X_test) # use the predict method of the object
```

All the available methods of the OLS object can be found here: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you